# Transforming single XML file with multiple XSLT files

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I am looking for a solution to transform an XML file with multiple XSLT files.

I have several tabs on my web UI. Each UI tab contains one XSLT file. While building an UI, I want to render using multiple tabs with one XML.

For example, I have four tabs in my UI, each tab has separate XSLT file, and only one data XML. I want to apply this data XML with my multiple XSLT files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to have templates in your xslt file that will match the data once for every tab you have. In this templates you can then format your data for each tab individually. You don't need multiple xslt files.

You can also use `<xsl:include>` to include multiple xsl files into one file. See http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_include.asp for further information.

Comment: I am doing the way you told me, but my XSLT has become big file more than 18,000 lines of code are there, so maintenance become big issues, so wanted to separate XSLT files depends upon tab logic, please help .

Comment: I edited my answer. You can split your files up and include them into one file which will then be used by the html file as stylesheet.